# flutter: Unhandled Exception: Unable to RTCPeerConnection::createAnswer: Error (null)

Tags: flutter, networking, video, webrtc, videocall

Guys I quite not understand this exception, anyone encountered this before ?

Libraries I use:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_webrtc: ^0.2.8
  toast: ^0.1.5
  web_socket_channel: ^1.1.0
  random_string: ^1.1.0
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.10
  http: ^0.12.0+4
  simple_permissions: ^0.1.9
  sdp_transform: ^0.2.0
```

My intention was to try to connect a call in `0.0.0.0` using `flutter_webrtc: ^0.2.8` following tutorial of this project : https://github.com/jamalag/flutter-webrtc-part2.

I coded in Flutter (main.dart)

```
/// Server Changes Here 服务器在此更改
  _createPeerConnection() async {
    Map<String, dynamic> config = {
      "iceServers": [
        {"url": "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"},
      ],
    };

    final Map<String, dynamic> offerSdpConstraints = {
      "mandatory": {
        "OfferToReceiveAudio": true,
        "OfferToReceiveVideo": true,
      },
      "optional": [],
    };

    _localStream = await _getUserMedia();

    RTCPeerConnection pc =
        await createPeerConnection(config, offerSdpConstraints);

    if (pc != null) print('HERE ==> $pc');

    pc.addStream(_localStream);

    pc.onIceCandidate = (e) {
      if (e.candidate != null) {
        print(json.encode(
          {
            'candidate': e.candidate.toString(),
            'sdpMid': e.sdpMid.toString(),
            'sdpMlineIndex': e.sdpMlineIndex,
          },
        ));
      } else {
        print('无效');
      }
    };

    pc.onIceConnectionState = (e) {
      print(e);
    };

    pc.onAddStream = (stream) {
      print('addStream:' + stream.id);
      _remoteRenderer.srcObject = stream;
    };

    return pc;
  }

  _getUserMedia() async {
    final Map<String, dynamic> mediaConstraints = {
      'audio': false,
      'video': {
        'facingMode': 'user',
      },
    };

    MediaStream mediaStream = await navigator.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints);

    _localRenderer.srcObject = mediaStream;
    _localRenderer.mirror = true;

    return mediaStream;
  }

  initRenderers() async {
    await _localRenderer.initialize();
    await _remoteRenderer.initialize();
  }

  requestPermission() {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      AndroidOperatingSystemPermission().requestAndroidUserPermission();
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      IOSOperatingSystemPermission().requestIOSUserPermission();
    } else {
      logger('没有这样的操作系统');
    }
  }

  void _setCandidate() async {
    String jsonString = sdpController.text;
    dynamic session = await jsonDecode('$jsonString');
    print(session['candidate']);
    dynamic candidate = RTCIceCandidate(
        session['candidate'], session['sdpMid'], session['sdpMlineIndex']);
    await _peerConnection.addCandidate(candidate);
  }

  void _setRemoteDescription() async {
    String jsonString = sdpController.text;
    dynamic session = await jsonDecode('$jsonString');
    String sdp = write(session, null);

    RTCSessionDescription description =
        RTCSessionDescription(sdp, _offer ? 'answer' : 'offer');

    print(description.toMap());

    // debugPrint(description.toMap().toString(), wrapWidth: 2048);

    await _peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(description);
  }

  void _createOffer() async {
    RTCSessionDescription description =
        await _peerConnection.createOffer({'offerToReceiveVideo': 1});

    var session = parse(description.sdp);

    print(json.encode(session));

    _offer = true;

    // print('__CREATE_OFFER__');

    print(
      json.encode({
        'sdp': description.sdp.toString(),
        'type': description.type.toString(),
      }),
    );

    _peerConnection.setLocalDescription(description);
  }

  void _createAnswer() async {
    RTCSessionDescription description =
        await _peerConnection.createAnswer({'offerToReceiveVideo': 1});
    var session = parse(description.sdp);

    debugPrint(json.encode(session), wrapWidth: 2048);


    _peerConnection.setLocalDescription(description);
  }
```

The Error I have encountered :

```
2020-09-22 16:54:56.539143+0800 Runner[603:86509] [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to RTCPeerConnection::createAnswer: Error (null)
#0      RTCPeerConnection.createAnswer (package:flutter_webrtc/rtc_peerconnection.dart:237:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      _CallerAppState._createAnswer (package:/main.dart:190:31)
#2      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:992:19)
#3      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1098:38)
#4      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:184:24)
#5      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:524:11)
#6      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:284:5)
#7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:256:7)
#8      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:158:27)
#9      GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:224:20)
#10     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:200:22)
#11     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:158:7)
#12     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:104:7)
#13     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:88:7)
#14     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1206:13)
#15     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
#16     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
#17     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:267:10)
#18     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:176:5)
```

The Method I had tried to solve this,

```
 debugPrint(json.encode(session), wrapWidth: 2048);
```

to print out a clear and long output , I thought this was the problem. As I am new to this , I need some clue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without seeing all the code it's hard to tell, but seems like you are trying to create an answer to a PeerConnection that has not been initialized or it is not correctly defined. Keep in mind that offers and answers need a negotiation channel (websockets) and you should answer a PeerConnection that has the right remote descriptor given by the offer. 

I think this could help you understand:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Signaling_and_video_calling

Comment: @JoanPicornell Thanks For the Documentation. I appreciate that. actually the code I provide is just the logic layer, while the rest are UI component. For the offer I did  copied and inserted into the Textfield of the UI component. But It raised exceptions, Could this be that my print out was line breaking line by line ?

Comment: So you are copying and pasting offer's sdp to repond to them? that could raise problems. Maybe you check the flutter webrtc demo and try to do a local loop call: https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/flutter-webrtc-demo This way you can spot differences between your code and theirs. As the output of the error is minimal, there isn't much you can do but debug and try to follow the guidelines as much as you can.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of using  `_localRenderer.mirror = true;` I'm using  `RTCVideoView(_localRenderer, mirror: true),`

I followed him on YouTube and worked for me.
You can follow him [or my code](https://github.com/yeasin50/Flutter-Video-Calling-App/blob/master/lib/screens/call_page.dart).